# Kali permanently remove sign-in and GUI

Tags: raspberry-pi, kali-linux, gui, display-settings

I was wondering if anyone knows how to remove sign in and gui for Kali? I am using a raspberry pi zero w 2 and therefore want to permanently remover these (To maximise speed).

Thanks,
Anon.

Comment: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/53467)

Comment: Raspberry PI is probably not the best for Kali.  Yes, I do use Kali and have a Raspberry PI as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. You want to run `sudo raspi-config` and go to `Boot Options>Desktop/CLI>Console` then exit and reboot

Comment: Congrats on figuring it out yourself. I don't think it removes the desktop - it probably merely prevents it from starting. But if you don't mind extra disk usage, that should be good enough